# Looking for web spider/download program which can use existing browser cookies and can process Javascript

Tags: browser, web-crawler

I'm looking for a program to spider a web site* and download the content to disk.  I've got the following requirements though which appear to trip up the programs I've tried:

1. The site's logon process is distributed between multiple pages so I need to be able to start the session manually with my web browser, authenticate, then launch the spider and give it access to the cookies.
2. Many of the links execute Javascript and then return content.
3. Many of the links return PDF documents (some spiders do support this).

So far though I'm unable to find a spider that can handle #1 and #2.

* The site is a bill payment service and it has my bill history.  I'm looking to stop using the service but I want to keep the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tennyson Maxwell's [Teleport Ultra](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/ultra/home.htm) fulfills your requirements.